# Django - Change active navbar template based on webpage

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

I have a template that looks like this in my html. It uses the bootstrap classes.

```
  <-- navbar-template.html>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="/home/">Home</a></li>
      <li class='active'><a href="/members/">Members</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Research</a></li> 
      <li><a href="#">Publications</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>  
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I like the active class but I need the  to change which list object it is based on which page from the navbar django has loaded.

I think you'd like to do something like this in the home.html file

```
<-- HOME -->
{% include "navbar_template.html" with page="home"}  %}

###Do something with {{page}} variable in order to set the home list tag to active.
```

Do I have to write a crazy amount of if else statements or is there an easier way. Perhaps something with the views.py in django

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this (example solution I use on my page):

```
<ul class="sidebar-nav--primary">
  {% url 'main:home' as home %}
  {% url 'main:work' as work %}
  {% url 'main:personal' as personal %}

  <li><a href="{{ home }}" {% if request.path == home %}class="active"{% endif %}>Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="{{ work }}" {% if request.path == work %}class="active"{% endif %}>Work</a></li>
  <li><a href="{{ personal }}" {% if request.path == personal %}class="active"{% endif %}>Personal</a></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

A cleaner method would be creating a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags). Something like `is_active`:

```
# Inside custom tag - is_active.py
from django.template import Library
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
register = Library()

@register.simple_tag
def is_active(request, url):
    # Main idea is to check if the url and the current path is a match
    if request.path in reverse(url):
        return "active"
    return ""
```

And use it in your templates like this:

```
# template.html
{% load is_active %}
<li><a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="{% is_active request 'home' %}">Home</a></li>
```

Comment: Sow it's the same url class get empty string and? <a> tag is also active in both conditions.

Comment: @darek_82 the <a> tag has the css class "active" if the current url for the request  matches the django url 'home', else it doesn't have any css class.